# Can MS be done with full scholarship?

Tags: research-process, masters, professorship

Although graduating from a low ranked college I was able to become research associate at a well known research institution. My work there provided me with three research papers.

Is there any possibility of getting a full scholarship for a MS program?

Comment: How common it is to get scholarships for graduate work is highly field-dependent.  (In some fields, if you don't get a scholarship, they are really trying to tell you not to come at all.)  If you provide more specific information you will probably get more pertinent answers.

Comment: @Pete L Clark. My field is  computer vision and image processing.Do low ranked colleges provide full scholarship?

Answer (score 1):

I did an MS in math.  My tuition was waived and I received a stipend that was enough for me to live on (albeit very cheaply).  In return for this I taught one class of either business math or college algebra every semester I was there.  I think everyone that was there with me at the same time was on the same deal.

It shouldn't be hard to get this information from the school or schools of your choice.  If they have a program like this they probably recruit for it.

This might be different from what you are asking, since it more or less involves working for the money, but for anyone that needs a way to pay for a Master's degree, this is definitely a way to explore.  I can't say how common an arrangement like this would be outside of mathematics, however.

You should contact the school(s) you are considering attending and find out what kind of arrangements are made there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.  I personally had a full scholarship for my MS.  Even more specific, for example, no one from MIT media lab can be accepted WITHOUT a full scholarship (http://www.media.mit.edu/admissions/faqs) .  Your full scholarship is based on how much the university/professor/department needs you.  If you have the ability to perform at the level of a researcher or PHD student, there is no reason they would not want to pay for you to be working there.

Of course, this depends on both school and country.  Some places may have specific rules on how you can have a scholarship.  It may be contingent on teaching assistant or research assistant positions.